# Spring autowired Variable is not available for usage

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest-client

Am new to spring and spring boot. I was actually trying to a restclient in springboot. When i write the client and get the response, i wanted to read the response body which is String and wanted to convert that to JSON for my use. So i have written RestClient class and from that I have autowired JsonUtil class which does String to JSON. But my autowired jsonutil is  not available for me to use in Rest client class. i dont know what i need to do here. Below is my code.

My RestClient

```
@Component
public class RestClient {

    @Autowired
    JsonUtil jsonUtil;

    private static final String URL ="https://test.com?q=";

    private static String getURL(String value){
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(value))
            return URL+value;

        return null;
    }

    private static void get(String val){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String resourceUrl=getURL(val);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(resourceUrl)){
            response  = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl , String.class);
        }
    //Though i have autowired JsonUtil, i dont have that object to use it here
    jsonUtil.  //this variable is  not available
}
```

My JsonUtil

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Component
public class JsonUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    public JsonUtil(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }


    public JsonNode getStringAsJson(String value) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readTree(value);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = e.getMessage();
            LOG.info(msg);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You're trying to use an **instance** variable in a **static** method. That can't possibly work. Learn about the static keyword. This is fundamental stuff that needs to be mastered before using complex frameworks such as Spring. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an instance variable inside a static function. That is not possible. Think of it this way, there can be numerous instances of the class with each having its own particular instance variable. How will the static method know which one to pick.

You should make the methods non static to make it work.

However, if you are determined to make the function static make the variable also static and since you can't autowire static fields, try something like this

```
private static JsonUtil jsonUtil;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    jsonUtil = ctx.getBean(JsonUtil.class);
}
```